# imagecopyresized() invalid image dimensions?

Tags: php, image, function

I get the following error when trying to create a thumbnail of an image:

```
Warning: imagecopyresized() [function.imagecopyresized]: Invalid image dimensions in H:\Programs\webserver\root\media\images\inc\func.php on line 160
```

This is the function I have created to do the job:

```
function create_thumbnail($image_type, $image_height, $image_height, $temp_dir, $thumb_path, $thumb_width, $thumb_height){
    switch($image_type){
        case 'image/jpeg';
            $img =      imagecreatefromjpeg($temp_dir);
            $thumb =    imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
                        imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height);
                        imagejpeg($thumb, $thumb_path, 100);


        break;
        case 'image/png';
            $img =      imagecreatefrompng($temp_dir);
            $thumb =    imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
                        imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height );
                        imagepng($thumb, $thumb_path, 100);

        break;
        case 'image/gif';
            $img =      imagecreatefromgif($temp_dir);
            $thumb =    imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
                        imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height );
                        imagegif($thumb, $thumb_path, 100);

        break;
    }

}
```

Which is used like so:

```
// Create the new thumbnail dimensions
                        list($thumb_width, $thumb_height) = thumb_dimensions($case, $image_width, $image_height);

                        // Create the thumbnails
                        create_thumbnail($image_type, $image_height, $image_height, $temp_dir, $thumb_path, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
```

The thumb dimensions are width: 100px, height: 99px;

Comment: You know that `imagecopyresized` expects `int` parameters for dimensions, not CSS-style `100px` strings, right?

Comment: yeah I just added those in for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo in the function definition:

```
function create_thumbnail($image_type, $image_height, $image_height, ...
                                           ^^------dupe----^^
```

which means `$image_width` isn't defined and will probably evaluate to 0.

Same goes for your sample `create_thumbnail()` call at the end - two image_heights, no image_width.

Comment: Sigh, must be a sign to call it a night. Thank you.